# extract the object from a vector with the smallest value

Tags: r

I have the following vector

```
a <- 0.01
b <- 0.1
c <- 0.0001

x <- c(a,b,c) 

Which.min provides the location
min provides the minumum value
```

Would like to extract the object name (either a,b or c) that corresponds to the smallest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cbind` instead of `c`.  Not for large samples...

```
x <- cbind(a, b, c)
colnames(x)[which.min(x)]
# [1] "c"
```

This is horribly inefficient, but it does save you having to define names.  Also, will not work if your vectors have more than one value.

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c(a=0.01, b=0.1, c=0.0001)
names(x)[which.min(x)]
```

Comment: Is there any other way as I cannot make a list because is too long, this is an example

Comment: I don't understand. In your question you said you had a vector. If your vector has names, then the code above gives you the name of the element with the least value. Isn't that what you wanted? Do you mean that you have some variables and that you want the name of the variable with the least value? An example that corresponds exactly to your situation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think Barnaby wants to do this for objects in the environment:

```
a <- 0.01
b <- 0.1
c <- 0.0001

names(which.min(sapply(ls(), get, envir=globalenv())))
# [1] "c"
```

Note this will grab every object in the environment, so if you don't want that you either need to clean your environment, or use the `pattern` argument to `ls`.

Really though, if you are resorting to this type of trick you're probably doing your analysis wrong.  Like objects should typically be kept together (e.g. in lists).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector with variable names:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c") 

names(which.min(mget(x)))
# [1] "c"
```